# How to use this function to grab a div

Tags: php, regex, html

I found this function in snipplr which grabs ra div with certain attribute.  I tried to use it, but it didn't work.  Is there a something wrong in my way of using it?

http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=20987

```
function get_tag( $attr, $value, $xml, $tag=null ) {
  if( is_null($tag) )
    $tag = '\w+';
  else
    $tag = preg_quote($tag);

  $attr = preg_quote($attr);
  $value = preg_quote($value);

  $tag_regex = "/<(".$tag.")[^>]*$attr\s*=\s*".
                "(['\"])$value\\2[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\\1>/"

  preg_match_all($tag_regex,
                 $xml,
                 $matches,
                 PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  return $matches[3];
}
```

I made a change on it to use it for a url like this:

```
    function get_tag( $attr, $value, $page, $tag=null ) {
  if( is_null($tag) )
    $tag = '\w+';
  else
    $tag = preg_quote($tag);

  $attr = preg_quote($attr);
  $value = preg_quote($value);

  $tag_regex = "/<(".$tag.")[^>]*$attr\s*=\s*".
                "(['\"])$value\\2[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\\1>/";
 $page = file_get_contents($page);
  preg_match_all($tag_regex,
                 $page,
                 $matches,
                 PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  return $matches[3];
}


get_tag("class","weather","http://www.masrawy.com","div");
```

How can I use this correctly?

Comment: Should you be checking the error return from `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: The reason why the regular expression doesn't work is because in the page you're loading, the `div` with `class="weather"` contains a nested `div`, so the end tag of the inner div would be found, not the outer tag.  Definitely use a DOM parser as in @prodigitalson's answer..

Answer (score 2):

Dont use a regex for this. Use something that can parse and query the DOM like `DOMDocument`, `Zend_Dom_Query` or `SimpleHTMLDOM`.

DOMDocument example:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.masrawy.com');
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="weather";
$nodes = $finder->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

$extracted = array();
foreach($nodes as $element)
{
  // convert to html string
  $extracted[] = $element->ownerDocument->saveXML($element);
}

// now iterate over extracted and output...
```

An Zend_Dom_Query example:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.masrawy.com");

$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$results = $dom->query('div.theCssClassName');

$extracted = array();
foreach($results as $element)
{
  // convert to html string
  $extracted[] = $element->ownerDocument->saveXML($element);
}

// now iterate over extracted and output...
```

Comment: thanks prodigitalson for this,but  i hope if u can help me with this snippet to make the same job,because i am not familiar with zend framework,as i just use codeigniter

Comment: Its not going to work with that snippet consistently, and definitely not right now (see Jacobs comment to your initial question). You dont need to know much about ZF beyond the snippet i gave you. You just need to add the `Zend_Dom_Query` component and its dependencies as a library in CI like you would with any 3rd party lib. However if you dont want to do that I have updated my answer with an example using PHP's native `DOMDocument`. You could also use SimpleHTMLDOM which alot of people seem to use, but i never have - thus no example for that one :-)